# Read a CSV to insert data into Postgres SQL with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I want to read a csv file to insert data into postgres SQL with Python
but I have these error:

```
  cursor.execute(passdata)
  psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "prk_constraint_project"
  DETAIL:  Key (project_code)=(%s) already exists.
```

My code is:

```
  clinicalCSVINSERT = open(clinicalname, 'r')
  reader = csv.reader(clinicalCSVINSERT, delimiter='\t')
  passdata = "INSERT INTO project (project_code, program_name ) VALUES ('%s', '%s')";
  cursor.execute(passdata)
  conn.commit()`
```

What does this error mean?
Is it possible to have a working script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Comment: My CSV contains data like that : 

`

                  file_uuid 1B3DB121-B766-486D-AB7D-65AB646CE5AC      
                  batch_number 304.63.0     
                  project_code TCGA     
                 disease_code ACC     
                 day_of_dcc_upload 31         
                 month_of_dcc_upload 3
                 year_of_dcc_upload 2016
                 (data are tab separate values)

`

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem with your code is that you are trying to include the literal `%s`. Since you probably did run it more than once you already have a literal `%s` in that unique column hence the exception.

It is necessary to pass the values wrapped in an iterable as parameters to the `execute` method. The `%s` is just a value place holder.

```
passdata = """
    INSERT INTO project (project_code, program_name ) 
    VALUES (%s, %s)
"""
cursor.execute(passdata, (the_project_code, the_program_name))
```

Do not quote the `%s`. Psycopg will do it if necessary.

As your code does not include a loop it will only insert one row from the csv. There are some patterns to insert the whole file. If the requirements allow just use [`copy_from`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) which is simpler and faster.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer,

Comment: my CSV has 2 columns ;

Comment: the first one contains several data including project_code and program_name, the second columns contains data corresponding to the first column